# Dictionary in Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, dictionary, sh

I am developing service manager in centos8 and I have this code to get services:

```
i=0
while [ $i -lt $service_count ]; 
do
    service_name=`cat $service_conf_file | get_json_value "['service_groups'][$i]['service']" | sed 's/"//g'`
    status_reader $service_name
    if [ $service_disabled -eq 1 ]; then 
        current_status=disabled
    fi
    
    echo "{'${service_name}' : '${current_status}'}"
    
    
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
   
done
```

But this code returns:

```
{'apache_server' : 'running'}
{'apache_server_2' : 'running'}
```

I want it in dictionary like below,  which I can access later by service name using Python.

```
{"apache_server" : "running" , "apache_server_2" : "running"}
```

How to do it ?

Comment: Use printf as opposed to echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

printf "{"

i=0
j=100
target=10

while [ $i -lt $target ]; do

    printf "\"$i\" : \"$j\""

    if [ $i -lt $(( $target - 1 )) ]; then
            printf ", "
    fi

    i=$(( i + 1 ))
    j=$(( j + 1 ))
done

printf "}\n"
```

which produces this kind of output:
`{"0" : "100", "1" : "101", "2" : "102", "3" : "103", "4" : "104", "5" : "105", "6" : "106", "7" : "107", "8" : "108", "9" : "109"}`

---

So in your case something like this should be ok:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

printf "{"

i=0

while [ $i -lt $service_count ]; do
    service_name=`cat $service_conf_file | get_json_value "['service_groups'][$i]['service']" | sed 's/"//g'`

    status_reader $service_name

    if [ $service_disabled -eq 1 ]; then
        current_status=disabled
    fi

    printf "\"$service_name\" : \"$current_status\""
    
    if [ $i -lt $(( $service_count - 1 )) ]; then
            printf ", "
    fi

    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done

printf "}\n"
```

---

As suggested in the comment the trick here's using `printf` that doesn't automatically place the newline "\n" at the end of the string.
You could use `echo` too but specifying the `-e` option.
Anyway not every systems supports that option so simply use `printf`, just to be sure.

---

As another note:
Looking at the desired output it seems you want a json payload, if you are able to use BASH over simple sh you can think about putting stuff into an array then converting it through some tool like [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) in order to prevent and manage syntactic errors.